# Jpa specification order by some values from the list

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, pagination, specifications

I use pagination with specification, how can I add sorting to existing sorting from pagination,
based on some enumeration values?
e.g. some status has values: A, B, C, D
I want to sort in a way that A and D be in the end of the page:

- B
- C
- A
- D

I tried to add:

```
    private static Specification<MyObj> getMySpec() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Expression<Object> cases = cb.selectCase()
                .when(cb.not(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("status"), "A"), cb.equal(root.get("status"), "D"))), 1)
                .when(cb.equal(root.get("status"), "A"), 2)
                .when(cb.equal(root.get("status"), "D"), 3);

        Order order = cb.asc(cases);

        return cb.equal(cb.literal(1), 1); //just to return something. 
    };
    }
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: Are you open to using JPQL here instead of Criteria builder?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it's not possible now :|